# Replacing big amount of documents from specific date in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, celery

I'm storing business/ statistical data by date in different collections.
Every day thousands of thousands of rows are being inserted.

In some cases my application fetches or generate information that includes let's say the last 20 days with new values, so I need to update that old information in MongoDB with the new values for those dates.

The first option I thought of is removing all rows **from** 20 days ago until now by removing by date, and insert the new data with insertMany().

The problem with this is that the amount of rows is **huge** and it blocks the database which some times makes my worker process to die (It's a python celery task).

The second option I thought of to is to split the new coming data into chunks per date (using Pandas dataframes), and perform a "removal" then "insert of that date, and iterate that process until today. This way is the same but in smaller chunks.

Is the last option a good idea?

Is there any better approach for this type of problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: 1000s of rows doesn't sound like a lot for a daily operation. How big is this data? It's max 16GB due to the 16MB per document limit. Can you use a TTL index to remove old data? Can you provide examples of your insert and delete queries?

Comment: @RobertSeaman 200.000 rows is a more realistic example. I guess I cannot use TTL because I should keep older data. The use case is that I have to delete, let's say last 30 days of data and insert the updated version

Comment: Splitting up into chunks sounds sensible. How comes it blocks the database? Are you using wiredTiger? Which Mongo version? Are you running out of wiredTiger write tickets? Are you using bulk insert?

Comment: I'm not using wiredTiger. MongoDB 3.6.10, I'm using insertMany() through chunks of 15k documents each time.

Comment: wiredTiger is the default storage engine in 3.2+ environments, unless you upgraded from 3.0 or lower which might be using mmap. Which storage engine are you using? Are 2 applications writing to the same collection? Can you chunk your data into smaller chunks if it's still an issue with the current chunk size? The clarify, the issue you're having is that other applications can't communicate with the database during a large write operation?